# Some hints on how can I improve the question on safety issues

Tags: discussion, scope

Yesterday I [a question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16517/pick-pocketing-rate-in-andalusia-compared-to-that-one-of-catalonia), which sounds to me 100% practical. I expected to get some advice on what places are considered to be relatively unsafe (like Ramblas in Barcelona), which kind of activities I should avoid (for example, don't mess with street flower sellers or something like that).

But the question was closed. User Rory Alsop, as well as some other users provided some arguments to explain why this question is not welcome here.

In my experience, in 99.9% percent of cases, when the community decides to close the question, the decision is valid. Moreover, I'm almost sure that this is true in case of my question as well. All I'm trying to ask is, can somebody give me some hints how can I improve this question in order to make it valuable or at least appropriate here?

I'm comparing my question [to this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4393/comparative-safety-of-countries-in-central-america?rq=1) and can see no conceptual difference. So, what can I do to make my question appropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've expected to get some advices what places considered to be relatively unsafe (like Rambla in Barcelona), which kind of activities I should avoid (for example, don't mess with street flower sellers or something like that).

If you expect this kind of answer, than ask "**which kind of activities should I avoid?** or "**which places should I avoid?**". Try to ask questions that are not too general.

You can also split your question. IMHO it's not good when you ask for many cities at once.
But you're right that your question is simular to the question about the safety in Central America, which is also not really good fit for our Q&A format. It's an old question and if it would be asked again now, it would get some close votes too.

Comment: Yes, this is the key - the Central America question was only 6 months after the start of the site, it was still getting defined, and now would be closed to being too broad.